# how to solve bad operand issue?

Tags: java

Hi everyone been a rookie in this platform just wanna get things straight like whats the right method to do the below work the task is to count no of characters and vowels in a given string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class wordchk1
{


    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter string: ");
        String text = scan.nextLine();
        countVowel(text);

    }



    public static void countVowel(String S)
    {

        int i,c=0,ln;
        char ch;
        ln=S.length();

        for(i=0;i<ln;i++)
        {
            ch=S.charAt(i);
            if(ch=='a'||ch=='e'||ch=='i'||ch=='o'||ch=='u')
            {
                c++;
            }
        }

       System.out.println("number of vowels ="+c);
       System.out.println("number of consonants are="+S.length()-c);

    }
}
```

The error that pops out seems to some kind of bad operand ...
Thanks

Comment: Hmm ya that's where the error occurs any tip...??

Comment: Note the parentheses.

Comment: Are you sure that digits are consonants? What about punctuation?

Comment: WOW..!!Thx a ton.This is quite ridiculous

Comment: If you've solved the issue ,then try answering your own question as it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `System.out.println("number of consonants are="+S.length()-c);` to `System.out.println("number of consonants are="+(S.length()-c));`. The reason is that when the program simplifies your equation, the following happens without the extra parenthesis.

```
"Number of consonants are=" + S.length() - c
"Number of consonants are=" + 6 - 2
"Number of consonants are=6" - 2
```

Because you cannot subtract something from a String, meaning that the `-` operand is bad, you get a bad operand exception. Adding the parenthesis makes it do this instead.

```
"Number of consonants are=" + (S.length() - c)
"Number of consonants are=" + (6 - 2)
"Number of consonants are=" + 4
"Number of consonants are=4"
```

Because the parenthesis are there, the program prioritizes that part of the equation first, which solves the problem. This follows the Order of Operations, which you can [google](http://bit.ly/HfAifl) and read all about.

The reason you can add things to Strings is that, (depending on the value), when you try to + something that isn't a String onto a String in Java, it converts that value to a String and then adds it. For example, `"I am " + 6` becomes `"I am " + "6"` which becomes `"I am 6"`.

Answer (score 0):

String and primitive are not valid operands for binary `-`.
ONLY `binary + operator` is valid for String and primitive operands.

[Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) for **String Conversion**
says:

> String conversion (§5.4) applies **only** to an operand of the **binary + operator** which is not a String when the other operand is a String.

The problem is in this statement:

> System.out.println("number of consonants are="+**S.length()-c**);

It should be

> System.out.println("number of consonants are="+**(S.length()-c)**);

Answer (score 0):

```
String s ="something";
String vowelarray[] = {}//vowel array
int countVowel = 0;

for : iterate  vowelarray
{
   countVowel += StringUtils.countMatches(s, vowelarray[i]);
}

s.length //to get length of String. you can maniputlate countVowel and s.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `s.length()-c` will not give the number of consonents. For example you have a string having numeric character in between. In that case your logic will fail unless you do some kind of validation. So i would suggest convert your each character to ASCII and compare the `int`. Then you will get the actual result.

```
int ascii = (int) character;
```

(The bad operand problem is already solved , so i am not giving any explanation.)